# How do I create an ssh keygen for main server through the jump server?

Tags: bash, ssh, server, remote-access, ssh-keygen

I have the following setup:

```
ssh -J username@jump_server username@actual_server
```

I end up typing the same password twice to log in everytime.

How do I create an ssh-keygen so that I can log in to actual_server after typing in the above command on my device?

Thank you!

Comment: There are many guides on how to use `ssh-keygen`, and related questions/answers here on SO.  What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: I know how to create a keygen if it is just 1 server. 
The trouble is with the jump server. Would I create a key from my PC to the jump server and then another from the jump server to the actual server?